# Querying datastore for all models that contain a certain element within a listproperty

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql, listproperty

Hey, I have a model like this:

```
class List(db.Model):
    user = db.ReferenceProperty(User)
    listname = db.StringProperty()
    published = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    score = db.IntegerProperty(required=False)
    tld = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    categories = db.StringListProperty()
```

Where a list could have multiple categories attached to it (hence the listproperty). I want to use these categories to build category pages so I need a query I can use to fetch all lists that have a particular category within their categories attribute. I've tried a few different approaches and none seem to work. Is there a query like this this? (the following doesn't work):

```
select * from List where 'Philosophy' in categories
```

If not, I'm going to have to do something like:

```
lists = List.all()
for list in lists:
    if 'Philosophy' in list.categories:
        #add this list to the lists to display on page
```

But this feels like it would be either incredibly slow or break somehow...

Any ideas? Thanks!

Tom

**UPDATE:**

Oops, I solved it sorry for the bother! For anyone who's interested you can just use a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM List where categories = 'Philosophy'
```

Which will match any list which has 'Philosophy' within the categories.

Comment: Thanks Riley - I'll add it as an answer and make sure I do that next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops, I solved it sorry for the bother! For anyone who's interested you can just use a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM List where categories = 'Philosophy'
```

Which will match any list which has 'Philosophy' within the categories.